# Where to run scheduled jobs in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, scheduled-tasks

I have a couple of simple jobs that are running on an old laptop everyday. The laptop wakes up, run the jobs and go back to sleep. Most of those jobs are simply C# / Python programs who are collecting a couple of information on the Web and send me what I need in an email or file.

I would like to move away from that model of running jobs on an old laptop. I could move those jobs in the cloud, but I don't want to pay $50+ a month to run those jobs on a VM that I will use only 5 minutes a day.

My question is the following: Is there a cloud service that runs jobs on a specific schedule where you pay only for what you use? As far as I know, Azure requires a VM, same for Amazon.

Answer (score 9):

If you are willing to learn a bit about some AWS features, there is a way to launch an EC2 instance on a cron-type schedule, passing in a script to run, and have it terminate itself when it's done processing.

The basic steps include:

1. Create a user-data script with your batch job (can install software, download data, etc.)
2. Create an Auto Scaling launch configuration that defines the instance type, AMI, and the user-data script from above.
3. Create an Auto Scaling group with the above launch configuration, and assign it a schedule to start instances.

I've detailed the exact steps including sample, working commands in this article:

> Running EC2 Instances on a Recurring Schedule with Auto Scaling
>   http://alestic.com/2011/11/ec2-schedule-instance

If your daily job can complete in less than an hour on a t1.micro instance, then you could end up spending as little as $1 a month, depending on I/O, network, and other resources you use.

Answer (score 2):

You can get a VM from [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) for $5/month (no affiliation).